# firebase array parse json always failed

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my printed  `print(childSnap)` and try to parse with `as? [String : Any]` but always failed any alternative .

```
   Snap (-Ki9GkBvIMofJiIByVeI) {
        location = Cupertino;
        name = "find hotel ";
        userCreatedId = "";
    }
```

---

```
 let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let allGroup = ref.child("all-group")
        allGroup.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            for  childSnap in snapshot.children{       
                   print(childSnap)

                if let _childSnap = childSnap as? [String : Any] {
                    //this code not execute.. 
                    let group = Group(json: _childSnap )
                    groups.append(group)
                }
            }

        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type cast `childSnap` to `FIRDataSnapshot` and then access `value` property of it.

```
if let _childSnap = (childSnap as! FIRDataSnapshot).value as? [String : Any] {
    let group = Group(json: _childSnap )
    groups.append(group)
}
```